# Conditional rendering in react for a multi language app in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multilingual, conditional-rendering

I am working on a react app that is going to be launched for different countries. In each country some components will be the same but others are going to be different.

i.e

```
France will have
  - Component A
  - Component B
  - Component C

Germany will have
  - Component A
  - Component D
```

So, both sites share similar components but some of them are unique.

We use a global env var to tell which site to load. (`en`, `fr`, etc)

Worth saying that the URL should be the same for all sites (the variable above should the one that tells the app which component to display)

What would be the best idea for handling this component differences?

Ideas that I`ve came up with until today:

- Create one site per country. (Big problem since too much DRY. There are shared many components)
- Conditional rendering (Feels hacky, since there are several countries, leading to endless `if` `else`)
- High Order component that returns all the components inside a parent container component (Feels good, but I did not want to reinvent the wheel and I wanted to ask here first)

Is there a NPM package that will help me archive this?

Should I start from scratch?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your first 2 options are too broad for an answer on SO, and your 3rd is essentially asking for an external resource, both of which are reasons for question closing. You probably have to do some more self-research, or attempt something, and ask a new question if you have a more specific question.

Comment: Thank you for you answer @TimLewis, agree on that. I thought about asking in Software Engineering. But since question is react-related, Software Engineering feels to wide to ask but Stack overflow to narrow.

Comment: Not sure if they would be able to help either tbh; I think the close reasons on SE sites are pretty similar. I like the sound of option 3, and you could look for localization plugins available for react.

Comment: This may be closed due to being more opinion based, so I'll add a comment rather than answer. This seems to be a good case for server side rendering. Another option rather than HOC could be to look into creating a custom hook to handle the conditional rendering.

Comment: I am suggesting a `Map` where key is language and value is component `[['fr',<CompA/>],[]]` the on the HOC filter needed components to render according to the key that matches selected language

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I get the point (sorry if that is the case). 
You don't need to create two sites. You just need to organize the site content in a passing structure (something like):

In the file with the site content:

```
const frenchData = [
  {
    idKey: 'aboutus',
    textTitel: aboutUsTextTitelFR,
    textField: aboutUsTextFieldFR
  }
];
const englishData = [
  {
    idKey: 'aboutus',
    textTitel: aboutUsTextTitelEN,
    textField: aboutUsTextFieldEN
  }
];


export const aboutusData = {
    'fr': frenchData,
    'en': englishData
}
```

You can get the preferred languages (from the user's browser) with the following lines.

`static async getInitialProps({ req }) {
    const userAgent = req ? req.headers['accept-language'] : navigator.userAgent;
    return { userAgent };
  }`

After making some string formating on the userAgent result, you will get an array of preferred languages. After that you need to render the passing data (DE, EN, ES, whatever)

Comment: Thank you for the response @alexis.

Your solution gives an approach on handling translated text. (which is good, we are doing the same).

But the current problem has to do with translated *components*. 

That means that we don´t need to return text, we need to return components according the site global language.